# using AND and OR

Tags: c#, mongodb

Trying to get a query that has both `AND` and `OR` to work in C#.

In SQL Server would be something like:

```
... where (Code = 'abc' OR Description = 'def') AND (Flag = 0)
```

With MongoVUE I seemed to have gotten it to work with this:

```
{ "$or" : [{ "Description" : /def/i }, { "Code" : /abc/i }], "$and": [{ "Flag" : 0 }] }
```

but can't seem to get it with the C#:
tried this:

```
List<IMongoQuery> qryValue = new List<IMongoQuery>();
qryValue.Add(Query.EQ("Code", "abc"));
qryValue.Add(Query.EQ("Description", "def"));
qryValue.Add(Query.And(Query.EQ("Flag", 1)));
var query = Query.Or(qryValue.ToArray());
```

but get this back:

```
{ "$or" : [{ "Code" : "abc" }, { "Description" : "def" }, { "Flag" : 1 }] }
```

and this doesn't give the correct results: missing the `AND` part.

Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that back because you're are putting all of your `Query.EQ` into the `Query.Or` on the last line.  Passing in a single value to a `Query.And` doesn't do anything; it's the same as if you passed a single value to any other method.  You haven't and-ed it with anything.

You need to write it in code as you have above in SQL: **respect the parenthesis**.

Group your `Or` together first, and pass it as the first parameter to the `And`, followed by the single, additional clause for `Flag`.

```
var clauses = new[] { Query.EQ("Code", "abc"), Query.EQ("Description", "def") };
var query = Query.AND(Query.OR(clauses), Query.EQ("Flag", 1))
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Thank you!  Also works in MongoVUE; seems it doesn't need the $and part:   { "$or" : [{ "Code" : /abc/i }, { "Description" : /def/i }], "Flag" : 0 }